# PHP Framework with CouchDB support

Tags: couchdb, php

I'm looking for a PHP framework that supports CouchDB pretty well natively, I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889410/language-framework-support-for-interacting-with-couchdb) that Ruby-on-rails or Django would work best, but I am looking for a PHP solution, as I'd like to not have to learn a new language just yet.

features needed outside of CouchDB are minimal:

- MVC architecture
- Templating engine for the Views (Although i could hack this in myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually CouchDB will be only the part of your application dealing with persistence, so your best bet is to choose your favorite framework (like Zend Framework or CodeIgniter) for MVC and templating, them choose a [PHP CouchDB library](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_PHP) to do your persistence/model layer instead of a regular ORM.